# How to load datetimepicker with different date-range for multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want new date range in each box, but it return only last text-box date range. I also made text boxes id's dynamic but still I am facing this issues. I have start date and end date for each text box and I calculated date range in PHP for start date and end date and disabled all those dates which is selected by user in their start date and date all is working fine but it returns last textbox dates disabled in datepicker.

Here is the screenshot-

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOgip.png)

Javascript function for datepicker to disbaled dates for each box -

```
$(function () {
  var count = $('#count').val();
  var uid = $('#usersId').val();
  var pid = $('#projectsId').val();
  for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    $('#projectAssStartDate' + i).datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        minDate: 0;
        alert(dateRange);
        console.log(dateString);
        return [dateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1];
      }
    });

    var date_range = $('#calendarDateString' + i).val();

    var newdate = date_range.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '');
    var res = '"' + newdate + '"';
    var startDate, endDate, dateRange = res;

    $('#projectAssEndDate' + i).datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        console.log(dateString);
        return [dateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1];
      }
    });
  }
});
```

HTML for create boxes id's dynamic and fetch values from it.

```
<input type="text" class='datepicker' size='11' title='D-MMM-YYYY' name="projectAssStartDate[]" id="projectAssStartDate<?php echo $id;?>"  value="" style="padding: 7px 8px 7px 8px;font-weight: bold;" />

<input type="text" class='datepicker' size='11' title='D-MMM-YYYY' name="projectAssEndDate[]" id="projectAssEndDate<?php echo $id;?>" value="" style="padding: 7px 8px 7px 8px;font-weight: bold;" />

<input id="calendarDateString<?php echo $id;?>" name="calendarDateString<?php echo $id;?>" title='D-MMM-YYYY' type="text" value="<?php echo $string;?>" />

<input id="projectsId" name="projectsId[]"  type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows['PROJECT_ID'];?>" />

<input id="usersId" name="usersId[]"  type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows['UM_ID'];?>" />
```

Comment: what is the count variable? and what is the 'id' of the datepicker that you got from php?
does it match?

Comment: the count is based on total no of textboxes, if i have two textbox then count is two. and which datepicker id you are taking about i did not get?

Comment: the two textboxes are assigned the id variable from php but the count variable is the number of rows i presume?
so how do the id variable and the count variable match?

is your id variable storing the count too?
i dont see looping there

Comment: count is also a kind of id where it returns total no of bosex and same with i hace started loop with 1 count.

Comment: yes id and count is same count is total no of textboxes and id is auto increment value.

Comment: if you can share the calendarDateString value let me check it from my end...

Comment: for first text box i am getting this data range - '2016-06-20','2016-06-21','2016-06-22', and for second text box - '2016-06-25','2016-06-26','2016-06-27','2016-06-28','2016-06-29','2016-06-30',, so it should show dates disabled according to this date.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer and reply whether this is the way you needed it to go. If not please comment what change you want with respect to this below code result. And I'm sorry that I have manipulated few of your values to ease my result. Will give details explanation if this is what you are expecting.

```
$(function () {
  var count = 2;//$('#count').val();
  var uid = $('#usersId').val();
  var pid = $('#projectsId').val();

// populate the array


var startDatearray= ["index 0","2016-06-15","2016-06-20"]; // you dont need to create this array .. just fetch these dates from your database as u need
var endDatearray=["index 0","2016-06-21","2016-06-25"];
var i;
  for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

    $('#projectAssStartDate' + i).datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var  i=parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''), 10); // as i wont get here so i took it from the current id
        var startDate = startDatearray[i], // some start date
        endDate  = endDatearray[i];  // some end date
        var dateRange = [];
        for (var d = new Date(startDate); d <= new Date(endDate); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
                dateRange.push($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d));

        }
        var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        minDate: 0;
        //alert(date);
        console.log(dateString +"__"+[dateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1] +"__"+dateRange);
        return [dateRange.indexOf(dateString) != -1]; // if u need the opposit then you can use { == -1} 
      }
    });

    var date_range = $('#calendarDateString' + i).val();

    var newdate = date_range.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '');
    var res = '"' + newdate + '"';
    var startDate, endDate, dateRange = res;

    $('#projectAssEndDate' + i).datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        console.log(dateString);
        var  i=parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''), 10); // as i wont get here so i took it from the current id
        var startDate = startDatearray[i], // some start date
        endDate  = endDatearray[i];  // some end date
        var dateRange = [];
        for (var d = new Date(startDate); d <= new Date(endDate); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
                dateRange.push($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d));

        }
        var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        minDate: 0;
        //alert(date);
        console.log(dateString +"__"+[dateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1] +"__"+dateRange);
        return [dateRange.indexOf(dateString) != -1]; // if u need the opposit then you can use { == -1}
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot Nazir, it perfectly fine, i have made little bit changes in array of dates..Really big thanks for u Nair Ranjith :-)

Comment: thanks neha and im glad that helped you..Please leave a +ve vote and help us too.. ;)